# Optimize mysql with inner joins and where

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mariadb

I have query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.id,
                h.host
FROM pozycje p
INNER JOIN hosty h ON p.host_id = h.id
INNER JOIN keywordy k ON k.id=p.key_id
AND k.bing=0
WHERE h.archive_data_checked IS NULL LIMIT 20
```

It's fast when some rows exists but if no results exists it takes 2,3 sek to execute. I would like to have less than 1 sec. Explain looks like:

http://tinyurl.com/gogx42n

Table pozycje has 30 000 000 rows, hosty has 4 000 000 rows and keywordy has 40 000 rows. Engine InnoDB, server with 32GB RAM

What indexes or improvements can I do to spped up query when no results exists?

edit:

show table keywordy;

```
 CREATE TABLE `keywordy` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `main_kw` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `keyword` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `lang` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `searches` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cpc` float NOT NULL,
 `competition` float NOT NULL,
 `currency` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `adwords` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `monitoring` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `bing` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `keyword` (`keyword`,`lang`),
 KEY `id_bing` (`id`,`bing`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38362 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Have you done ANALYZE TABLE ... on each of those tables recently. The indexes look OK, but with an index added on _archive_data_checked_ on _hosty_ I would hope it can reduce the rows to join greatly before joining to _pozcyje_ and then to _keywordy_

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE keywordy;

Comment: ANALYZE TABLE was done never. SHOW CREATE TABLE keywordy added

Comment: Running ANALYZE TABLE might be worthwhile when quiet as it might not be using up to date statistics to decide which index(s) to use. And make sure there is an index on archive_data_checked on hosty

Answer (score 0):

can pls test this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.id,
                h.host              
FROM hosty h
WHERE
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM keywordy WHERE id=p.key_id AND bing=0)
  AND
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pozycje WHERE host_id = h.id)
  AND h.archive_data_checked IS NULL LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Unknown column 'p.key_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @ekapek - i removed one EXISTS : SELECT DISTINCT h.id,
                h.host              
FROM hosty h
INNER JOIN pozycje p ON p.host_id = h.id
WHERE
  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM keywordy WHERE id=p.key_id AND bing=0)
  AND h.archive_data_checked IS NULL LIMIT 20

Comment: Time is similar as before >2 sek

Answer (score 0):

I would first offer the following question.  Which would have the smaller "set" if you did a query on

```
select count(*) from KeyWordy where bing = 0
vs
select count(*) from hosty where archive_date_checked IS NULL
```

I would then try to optimize the query knowing the smaller set and work with that as my primary criteria for indexing.  If KeyWordy is more likely to be the smaller set, I would offer your tables to have the following indexes

```
table       index
keywordy    (bing, id)   specifically NOT (id, bing) as bing FIRST is optimized for where or JOIN clause
pozycje     (key_id, host_id )
hosty       (archive_data_checked, id, host)

SELECT DISTINCT 
      h.id,
      h.host
   FROM 
      Keywordy k
         JOIN pozycje p
            ON k.id = p.key_id
            JOIN hosty h
               on archive_data_checked IS NULL
              AND p.host_id = h.id
   WHERE
      k.bing = 0
   LIMIT 
      20
```

if the HOSTY table would be smaller base on the archive_data_checked IS NULL, I offer the following

```
table       index
pozycje     (host_id, key_id )    reversed of other option

SELECT DISTINCT 
      h.id,
      h.host
   FROM 
      hosty h 
         JOIN pozycje p
            ON h.id = p.host_id
            JOIN Keywordy k
               on k.bing = 0
              AND p.key_id = k.id
   WHERE 
      h.archive_data_checked IS NULL 
   LIMIT 
      20
```

One FINAL option, might be to add the keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" such as

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT ... rest of query
```

If it works for you, what timing improvements does this offer.

Comment: Tested solution 1 and the best time was 2,1 sek MySQL done't use archive_data_checked_id_host index - with force to use this index query takes 10sek+